# How can I control the css of cloned <div> with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, duplicates, clone

I´m using sliders to control the background-color of a square.
For dynamically manipulating the stylesheet I am using the JQuery function

```
.css()
```

Then I duplicate this square a couple of times with

```
square.clone().insertAfter('#square');
```

Until now I have three squares which were all affected by the .css() function (see above).
But when I move a slider to change the color of the squares, only the first square is affected.
However, every square should change the color.

How can I do that?

See http://jsfiddle.net/0971yehk/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See http://jsfiddle.net/0971yehk/5/

You need to set the class on the original div and then change the handler to change the colour of the class, not the specific div. Cloning doesn't clone the id.

```
<div id="square" class="square" ></div>

$(".square").css("background-color",....
```

Comment: Thanks. Almost similar to the solution above but a Tick faster to edit

Comment: @wurstbrotrest No worries. Just remember to accept either of the answers.

Answer (score 1):

Use a **class** for the duplicated element instead of an "id" value. The "id" value needs to be unique, and that clearly won't be the case if you're cloning the elements.

```
<div class="square" ></div>
```

for the HTML and

```
// Color-Slider

$( "#red_slider, #green_slider, #blue_slider" ).slider(
{
    orientation: "horizontal",
    range: "min",
    max: 255,
    slide: changeColor,
    change: changeColor
});

// Slider Setup: Green

$( "#red_slider" ).slider( "value", 0 );
$( "#green_slider" ).slider( "value", 255 );
$( "#blue_slider" ).slider( "value", 0 );

function changeColor() 
{
    red_slider = $( "#red_slider" ).slider( "value" ),
    green_slider = $( "#green_slider" ).slider( "value" ),
    blue_slider = $( "#blue_slider" ).slider( "value" );

    // CSS Manipulation

    $(".square").css("background-color", "rgba(" + red_slider + "," + green_slider + "," + blue_slider + ")"); 
}

// dublicate squares

var square = $('.square');

for(var i = 1; i <= 2; i++)
{
    square.clone().insertAfter(square);
}
```

for the JavaScript and

```
.square
{
    width: 100px; height: 100px;
    background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0); /*red*/
    margin: 10px; float: left;
}
```

for the CSS. [Forked fixed fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/ypys3vsh/)

Comment: Thanks. This was very helpful.  Just replace the id of the square with a Class and it works!